# Processing Many-To-Many Relationships with Collection Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

My goal is to add many-to-many relationships between the `Viewer` model and the `Search` model through `ExlcudingViewers` via a collection select field. No relationships are actually created when I submit the form. Why is that?

Search model:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :viewers, through: :excluding_viewers
  has_many :excluding_viewers

  ...

  def excluding_viewers_list
    viewers.map(&:id)
  end

  def excluding_viewers_list=(ids)
    self.viewers.clear
    ids.each do |id|
      viewer = Viewer.find(id)
      self.viewers << viewer if viewer
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Viewer model:

```
class Viewer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :excluding_viewers
  has_many :searches, through: :excluding_viewers

end
```

ExcludingViewer model:

```
class ExcludingViewer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewer
  belongs_to :search
end
```

And the form I'm using for the search:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>

  ...

  <%= f.collection_select :excluding_viewers_list,
                          Viewer.order(:name),
                          :id,
                          :name,
                          {},
                          multiple: true,
                          class: "chosen-select" %>

   <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary search-cntrls" %>
<% end %>
```

The controller is working properly, and when I post the info from the form, the `:excluding_viewers_list` data is formatted like `["", "1", "3"]` if I select viewers with the id of 1 and 3

Comment: im not 100% but give it a try: `<%= f.collection_select(:excluding_viewers_list, Viewer.order(:name), :id, :name, {:include_blank => false}, {:multiple => true}) %>`

Comment: Added that, doesn't seem to have fixed the problem

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select i just select the options from there. and suggest you. You can also use prompt: "Select Any". if it might helps you